# Kotlin MutableLiveData not changing

Tags: kotlin, state, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a loginStatus value declared as MutableLiveData:

```
val loginStatus = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
```

When the user logins, the value will be changed to true in the viewModel:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
    loginStatus.value = true
    }
```

When the user logouts, the value is not changing to false even thought I make it false on logout function.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
    loginStatus.value = false
    }
```

I use **observeAsState** to look over the values:

```
loginViewModel.loginStatus.observeAsState(false).apply {
      Log.e(TAG, "LoginView: ${this.value}" )
      if (this.value) {
            //after login, this is always true
         }
      }
```

**loginStatus** is always true and I dont understand how because I change it to false.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

While using the Main thread to change the data, you should use the setValue() method of the MutableLiveData class and while using the background thread to change the LiveData, you should use the postValue() method of the MutableLiveData class.In this case you are using main thread, you can try :

```
loginStatus.setValue(true)
or
loginStatus.setValue(false)
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. setValue is the same as = operator.